# How to run another java code through my servlet?

Tags: java

I want to run another Java code in my servlet and wait till its execution completes.

[image]

In the image, I want to run `RSAKeyGenerator.java` in my `Servlet.java` and wait for it to complete execution.

The servlet.java has a normal servlet structure, while RSAKeyGenerator.java has a java program structure.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming `Servlet` and `RSAKeyGenerator` extend `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` and have a method like `public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){}` or `public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {}`?

Comment: The servlet.java has a normal servlet structur, while RSAKeyGenerator.java has a java program structure.

Comment: Why won't `RSAKeyGenerator generator = new RSAKeyGenerator();` work?

Comment: You can just call the `main` method. Method calls are synchronous in Java. This won't work if `RSAKeyGenerator` is not thread save or calls `exit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple create the object like this `RSAKeyGenerator generator = new RSAKeyGenerator()`

in servlet class and call the method using its reference

```
generator.xxxMethod();
```

Comment: I want to run the main method?

Comment: you have to call inside doGet() or doPost() methods in Servlet class

Comment: Okay, but the thing is I want to run the RSAKeyGenerator as a java program through the servlet...